# unable to connect to PPAS instance in HP Cloud using pgAdmin on Windows 7 PC

Tags: postgresql, cloud, remote-access, pgadmin, hp-cloud-services

With a fresh PPAS image in the HP Cloud, is it possible to connect to that remote image from pgAdmin running on a Windows 7 PC *without first making any changes to the PPAS configuration up in the cloud*? Does PPAS in the HP Cloud listen for remote connections "out of the box" so to speak?

I'm having no success-- getting an error that the server is not listening.  Using port 5444, and pointing pgAdmin at a text-file that contains the keypair the HP dashboard is telling me to use for the particular PPAS image when I click on "Connect to Server" link for the particular image.

Answer (score 1):

The server image is probably configured to listen to remote connections.  You can check that with `netstat -tapn` and verifying that there is a process listening on the appropriate port.

It's possible that you have not configured your security groups to allow external connections to port 5554.  Either add this to your default security group, or create a new security group and use it when creating new server instances.